# Make calculated in a dynamic table using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a problem with dynamic table using jQuery to calculate amount and total

this is  [`my code`](https://jsfiddle.net/bil/ezof47dm/1/)

amount = quantity * p.unit and total is sum of amount

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please clarify exactly what is not working, what is the "problem". It is also good to supply some example data or example tests and expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a lot of people will `tab` between fields. To this effect, I suggest binding to the `focus` and `blur` events. Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/epqhhtfc/

**HTML**

```
<table id="purchaseItems" name="purchaseItems" align="center">
  <tr>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>P.Unit ($)</th>
    <th>Amount ($)</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="next" required />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="price[]" class="next" required />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="amount[]" class="next last" required />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" name="addRow[]" class="add" value='+' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" name="addRow[]" class="removeRow" value='-' />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Total :</th>
    <td colspan='2' id="totalPrice"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#purchaseItems .add', function() {
    var row = $(this).parents('tr');
    var clone = row.clone();

    // clear the values
    var tr = clone.closest('tr');
    tr.find('input[type=text]').val('');

    $(this).closest('tr').after(clone);
    var total = 0;
    $(".last").each(function() {
      if (!$(this).val() == '') {
        total = total + parseFloat($(this).val());
      }
    })
    $("#totalPrice").html("$" + total);
  });
  $(document).on("blur", ".last", function() {
    var total = 0;
    $(".last").each(function() {
      if (!$(this).val() == '') {
        total = total + parseFloat($(this).val());
      }
    })
    $("#totalPrice").html("$" + total);
  });
  $(document).on('focus', ".last", function() {
    var $qty = $(this).parents("tr").find("input[name^='quantity']");
    var $pr = $(this).parents("tr").find("input[name^='price']");
    var $amnt = $(this).parents("tr").find("input[name^='amount']");
    var a = 0;
    if ($qty.val() == '' || $pr.val() == '') {
      console.log("No values found.");
      return false;
    } else {
      console.log("Converting: ", $qty.val(), $pr.val());
      var q = parseInt($qty.val());
      var p = parseFloat($pr.val());
      console.log("Values found: ", q, p);
    }
    a = q * p;
    $amnt.val(Math.round(a * 100) / 100);
  });
  $(document).on('click', '#purchaseItems .removeRow', function() {
    if ($('#purchaseItems .add').length > 1) {
      $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    }
  });
});
```

I adjusted the class names and field names to fit the column headers. When a row is added, or the `last` field loses focus, the `total` gets refreshed. I didn't go back and do this when a row is removed, but I think you can handle that.

Since fields are always a `string` value, I use `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` to cast them into usable values for Math. Once the calculation is done, I round it out to 2 decimal places. Focusing on the `last` field allows the user to tab or click to other fields, enter or change values at will and the amount will update. The only caveat here is that if the user changes the value and does not focus on the amount, no update.

So user can add a number of rows and then go back an populate them or they can populate a row and add a row. Either way works and allows the user to choose how they want to enter the data.

Not sure how `jquery` enters into this post.